# Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Environment windows 10, VSC 15

Using CreateProcessA winapi and passing lpenvironment variable to run python with scripts.
when lpenvironment is passed null, it works fine.
If I set environment variable PATH and PYTHONPATH = "paths", and pass that LPSTR(env.c_Str()), it throws above error on running.
The python version is 3.5.6

Any help?

---

Some more details.

1. I run child process python.exe "C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python_ML\mlprocessor_server.py" using CreateProcessA WINAPI.
2. I want to run child process with two environmental variables "PYTHONPATH" and "PATH".
   PYTHONPATH="C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\Scripts";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\include";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\Lib";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\libs";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\Lib\site-packages";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python_ML"
   PATH="C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\Lib";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\Scripts";"C:\Program Files\endpoint\Python\libs"

For some reason, the 7th parameter in CreateProcessA fails, the python.exe runs successfully if it is null, or else it prints "Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python".

### The way I set the parameter as follows...

std::string Base = Configuration::getBasePath();

```
std::string environPython = Base;
environPython.append("\\Python;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\Scripts;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\include;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\Lib;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\libs;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages;");
environPython.append(Base);
environPython.append("\\Python\\_ML;");
environPython.push_back('\0');


std::string environPath = Base;
environPath.append("\\Python;");
environPath.append(Base);
environPath.append("\\Python\\Lib;");
environPath.append(Base);
environPath.append("\\Python\\Scripts;");
environPath.append(Base);
environPath.append("\\Python\\libs;");
environPath.push_back('\0');

std::string cmd = Base;
cmd.append("\\Python\\python.exe");
std::string params = "\"";
params.append(cmd);
params.append("\" \"");
params.append(Base);
params.append("\\Python\\_ML\\mlprocessor_server.py\"");
```

std::map env = { { "PYTHONPATH", environPython.data() },
                                    { "PATH", environPath.data() }};

```
// example for generating block of strings
std::vector<char> envBlock;
std::for_each(env.begin(), env.end(),
    [&envBlock](const std::pair<std::string, std::string> & p) {
    std::copy(p.first.begin(), p.first.end(), std::back_inserter(envBlock));
    envBlock.push_back('=');
    std::copy(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(),   std::back_inserter(envBlock));
    envBlock.push_back('\0');
}
);
envBlock.push_back('\0');

// feed this into ::CreateProcess()
LPVOID lpEnvironment = (LPVOID)envBlock.data();

bool result = CreateProcessA(cmd.c_str(), (LPSTR)params.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, lpEnvironment, NULL, &info, &pi);
```

---

The result is always true, python.exe is not shown up in task manager and gives Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python.

If the lpEnvironment is NULL, python.exe is shown up in task manager.

Comment: You mean you set PYTHONPATH to the string literal "paths"?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` should be your project's root dir. And `PATH` should be your `/path/to/python` what do you even mean when you say '= "paths"'??

Comment: Python needs access to the system's entropy pool to initialise itself.  The message is telling you that Python could not get access, or that nothing was returned.

Comment: I updated the issue, can u review it once?

Comment: Request to let me know what is the issue in above code snippet?

Comment: Request for an update?

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 9):

The environment you pass to `CreateProcessA` must include `SYSTEMROOT`, otherwise the Win32 API call `CryptAcquireContext` will fail when called inside python during initialization.

When passing in NULL as lpEnvironment, your new process inherits the environment of the calling process, which has `SYSTEMROOT` already defined.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up with an example how this can very easily be triggered in pure Python software out in the real world, there are times where it is useful for Python to open up an instance of itself to do some task, where the sub-task need a specific `PYTHONPATH` be set.  Often times this may be done lazily on less fussy platforms (i.e. not Windows) like so:

```python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'print("hello world")'], env={
    'PYTHONPATH': '',  # set it to somewhere
})
```

However, doing so on Windows, will lead to the following perplexing failure:

```
Python 3.8.10 (...) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> p = Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'print("hello world")'], env={
...     'PYTHONPATH': ''
... })
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
Python runtime state: preinitialized
```

The fix is obvious: clone the `os.environ` to ensure `SYSTEMROOT` is in place such that the issue pointed out by @Joe Savage's answer be averted, e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> env = os.environ.copy()
>>> env['PYTHONPATH'] = ''
>>> p = Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'print("hello world")'], env=env)
hello world
```

Real world examples where this type of fix was needed:

- [Glean SDK](https://github.com/mozilla/glean/pull/1908/commits/b44f9f7c0c10fde9b495f61794253b051a0d3f62)
- [LocalStack's aws wrapper](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local/issues/46)
- [Perfect](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/4923)
- [`setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2315/commits/47ae38fd6f233e6423404bfebfd24d3b98fb897c) (only within the tests, but serves as an example showing how easily this mistake can be made by just about anyone).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your result unles I removed SYSTEMROOT

Comment: @openCivilisation Yes `Popen` failling because `SYSTEMROOT` isn't passed as one of the environment is the entire point of this answer? This is generally reproducible so wouldn't it be best to ensure this fix is included to prevent this problem even it might not affect your system personally?