# Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, localstack

I'm attempting to use the commands for localstack `awslocal` but unfortunately whenever I run any `awslocal` command I receive the error:

`Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python`

I can call localstack using the `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566` command so I don't think there's a problem there.

Comment: This might be a bug with how `localstack` invoked Python on Windows, please [refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997105/fatal-python-error-failed-to-get-random-numbers-to-initialize-python?rq=1).

Comment: This was reported to be fixed in [localstack/awscli-local#46](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local/issues/46#issuecomment-1009977609) via the v0.18 release.